# Change a global variable through a function: UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import rospy
import serial
import time
from std_msgs.msg import String

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
print (ser.name)
time.sleep(2)

#===========================================================
# An o y ine i kateuthynsi kinisis (mikos deksamenis)
# Gia kinisi se eutheia
x_d = 0 # mm
y_d = 2000
thita_d = 0 # moires i rads
#===========================================================

camera = [0, 0, 0]
error = [0, 0, 0]
data = [0, 0, 0]
print(data)
def camera_feedback():
    # dedomena apo camera-RPi-seiriaka apo allon komvo mallon...
    #camera = [x_c, y_c, thita_c]
    #x_c = camera[0]                    #isws mpei kwdikas gia na diavazei apo tin
    camera[0] = 0
    #y_c = camera[1]                    #seiriaki tu RPi (opws to serial_connection())
    camera[1] = camera[1] + 250
    #thita_c = camera[2]    
    camera[2] = 0
    print(camera)

def error_calculation():
    error[0] = x_d - camera[0]
    error[1] = y_d - camera[1]
    error[2] = thita_d - camera[2]
    print(error)

def controller_equations():
    # edw mpenun oi eksiswseis tu michali
    # kapws pernei to error kai alla dedomena kai dinei w, A, thita_mesi gia na stalun ston PIC
    if error != [0, 0, 0]:
        print(error)
        print(data)
        data[0] = 8
        data[1] = 8
        data[2] = 0
    else:
        data = [0, 0, 0]
    print('kokos')
    #data = [w, A, thita_mesi]     #na dw ti format dexete o kwdikas tu PIC

def serial_connection():
    rospy.init_node('serial_connection', anonymous = True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) #isws na min xreiazetai

    if not rospy.is_shutdown():

        ##data1 = bytearray(data)
        ##rdata = bytearray()
        ##rdata.extend(data1[0:2])
        ##rdata.extend(data1[2:5])
        ##vect = list(rdata)
        ##print(vect)

        if ser.isOpen():
            print ("Port Open")
            for i in range(1):
                #ser.write(b'5')
                #ser.write(chr(5)) auto stelnei kwdikopoiimenus xaraktires, ox$
                #ser.write(5)
                ser.write(bytes(data) + '\n')
                #print ('Hola!')
                #ser.write("Hola!\n")
                time.sleep(1)
                rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            camera_feedback()
            error_calculation()
            controller_equations()
            serial_connection()
        ser.close()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

I run the code above and I get the error:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment

I want to change the value of the global variable data through the function controller_equations(). I did the same with the variable camera in the function camera_feedback() without any error. I searched other posts for an answer but all of them say that is not possible to chance a global variable through a function. Any possible solution or a tip will be appreciated.  I am new in Python and I use Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 2.7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I too answered quickly it is to do with globals. now I'm curious too. There is an alignment issue in the controller_equations() code block. Am sure you would have got: IndentationError.  Hope you are getting UnboundLocalError after fixing this.  Is it possible to post the stack trace to confirm line  triggering this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out by duplicate post response, you need to use `globals` to solve this problem

However, to explain why it worked in `camera_feedback` but not in `controller_equations`

**You don't need  `globals` statement to access global variables directly in function context !!.**  However it is **not advised** to save your life time from debugging problem like this

To resolve a variable,  interpreter always looks in local name space for variable (precisely label) reference before searching in global (immediate parent) name space

In `camera_feedback`, interpreter looks in local name space  for variable `camera`, when it evaluates `camera[0] = 0`.
As it is not found it looks in its immediate parent (i.e module ) namespace

In `controller_equations` you have created a new environment context within function context by `if..else` statement. As the variable `data` is not found in local name space (`if..else context`, it would be looked in immediate parent i.e function context which also has no reference to `data`,so it throws `UnboundLocalError` error

To solve this you need to include  `data` from module name space to function name space by the statement `globals data` , so that all the nested environment within function can access them (Disclaimer: This is oversimplification of how internals handles scoping)

Hope this helps!